# Oracle polymorphic function (PTF) - pass parameters from another function

Tags: oracle, polymorphism

As a simple test based on
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HQK7TYEKEXFZOB62KONZXS3PY.html
let's consider this modified example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE poly_pkg AS  
  FUNCTION describe ( p_tbl IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T,  
                      p_var NUMBER )  
                      RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T;  
END; 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY poly_pkg AS  
  
  FUNCTION describe ( p_tbl IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T,  
                      p_var NUMBER )  
                      RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T AS  
  BEGIN  
    -- simply display the value passed in      
    DBMS_TF.TRACE( 'VAR = ' || p_var);
    RETURN NULL;  
  END;  
  
END; 
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION poly_func(p_tbl IN TABLE,  
                                     p_var NUMBER )  
  RETURN TABLE PIPELINED  
  ROW POLYMORPHIC USING poly_pkg; 
/  
  
-- for "bla" any table

SELECT * FROM poly_func(bla,33);
/*
will return
VAR = 33
*/

SELECT * FROM poly_func(bla,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY')));
/*
will return null (but if you put fetch_rows, the value was set in fetch rows but in describe still null!)
VAR = 
*/
```

Not sure if I missed something? The functions in the PTF body must be special (in what kind?)? Maybe this breaks the concept of polymorphic versus dynamic.

Oracle version
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

@edit - version with fetch

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE poly_pkg AS  
  FUNCTION describe ( p_tbl IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T,  
                      p_var NUMBER )  
                      RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T;  
    procedure fetch_rows(p_var NUMBER) ;
END; 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY poly_pkg AS  
  
  FUNCTION describe ( p_tbl IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T,  
                      p_var NUMBER )  
                      RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T AS  
  BEGIN  
    -- simply display the value passed in      
    DBMS_TF.TRACE( 'VAR = ' || p_var);
    RETURN NULL;  
  END;  
  procedure fetch_rows (p_var NUMBER ) as     
  begin     
     DBMS_TF.TRACE( 'VAR IN FETCH = ' || p_var);     
  end;  
  
END; 
/
```

and then run the same queries

```
VAR = 333
VAR IN FETCH = 333
VAR = 
VAR IN FETCH = 2023
```

Comment: Strange... var is null for extract(year) from sysdate, but is correct for power(5, 2) for example. And dump() shows null.

Comment: SYSDATE is not DETERMINISTIC.

Answer (score 1):

The `describe` function determines the shape of the result set - i.e. its columns and their data types. It's only processed during cursor compilation/parsing.

This has a couple of consequences:

- Many executions of the same SQL text will only execute `describe` once (assuming it's still in the cursor cache)
- Using bind variables, functions, etc. to determine row set shape could have unexpected/unwanted results if the cursor is invalidated

To mitigate the second point:

> While the constant scalar values are passed as-is to the DESCRIBE
> function, all other values are passed as NULLs.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-4847CB51-6939-44C4-9913-CC3CE13B6730

If you want to inspect (non `columns`) parameter values, do so in the `fetch_rows` procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE poly_pkg AS  
  FUNCTION describe ( p_tbl IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T,  
                      p_var NUMBER )  
                      RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T;  
                      
  PROCEDURE fetch_rows ( p_var NUMBER  );
END; 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY poly_pkg AS  
  
  FUNCTION describe ( p_tbl IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T,  
                      p_var NUMBER )  
                      RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T AS  
  BEGIN  
    -- simply display the value passed in      
    DBMS_TF.TRACE( 'DESCRIBE VAR = ' || p_var);
    RETURN NULL;  
  END;  
  
  PROCEDURE fetch_rows ( p_var NUMBER  ) AS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_TF.TRACE( 'FETCH VAR = ' || p_var);
  END fetch_rows;
  
END; 
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION poly_func(p_tbl IN TABLE,  
                                     p_var NUMBER )  
  RETURN TABLE PIPELINED  
  ROW POLYMORPHIC USING poly_pkg; 
/  
  

SELECT * FROM poly_func(dual,33);
/*
DESCRIBE VAR = 33
FETCH VAR = 33
*/
SELECT * FROM poly_func(dual,33);
/*
FETCH VAR = 33
*/

SELECT * FROM poly_func(dual,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY')));
/*
DESCRIBE VAR = 
FETCH VAR = 2023
*/

var v number;
exec :v := 2;
SELECT * FROM poly_func(dual,:v) p;
/*
DESCRIBE VAR = 
FETCH VAR = 2
*/
```

Comment: Yes read that but this is let's say a little bit unclear. Some internal function works some of them not. Of course, you could call the such function inside deterministic but expected that the result of the value will be also passed to fetch_row. Now it looks like function is not called on deterministic an then is call in fetch_row. Yes, this fit to unexpected/unwanted results but documentation could me more clear in this state.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean - please could you provide examples?

Comment: Yes, add fetch_row (sorry I wrote deterministic would like to write describe), I edit question. Function will be called when hit fetch_row is not at the describe level. As mention, this could be read as strange behavior and it is ok with documentation

Comment: Also from doc, param will be passed as a parameter not  as INT in this case but rather macro which in case declare is treated as NULL (doesn't matter deterministic or no) in fetch will be call. You can guess it from the documentation as it will work, but not right away ...

Comment: and eg. concat should be treat as function or operator or undefined bahaviour ? Because concat work (and probably other internal functions). Not sure why this work in such way (because you could pass eg. dynamic string to describe and call inside). As I mentioned, the documentation confirms this, but it is very subtle (not the first time  )

Comment: I'm still unsure what you're getting at here; it may be better submit a new question

Comment: This came out during the preparation of examples/models for classes. I actually wanted to make sure I understood the documentation correctly. Parameters to a polymorphic function must be written explicitly and not as an expression (if they are to go to function describe). Even if the function returns a scalar value and is deterministic it is not called this place (as mentioned this coincides with a polymorphic approach rather than a dynamic one).